# Can my app name be changed on playstore? I want to change actual app name(product name in unity) shown on user phone screen for my app published?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-development, playback

I want to chang my app name not playstore app name. But actual app name on phone. Is google allow it. Is violate any of their policy or changing it may result in new app on google store? Any help is truely appreciated. If possible ,I am ready to launch my update with new name.

Comment: yes you can change everything except your package name

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about a store policy, not programming. See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions-on-stack-overflow